# String Related Java programs

Tags: java, string

can  you help me why I got proper output though i have provided many spaces, this program is just counting the one space in `if/ else` condition

```
public class CountingtheCharactersinString
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String name = "This           is              my  first demo";
      int count = 0;
      boolean b = true;
      for(int i =0; i<name.length(); i++)
      {
          if(name.charAt(i)==' ')   b = true;
          else if(b==true)
          {
              b= false;
              count = count+1;
          }
      }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the error you are having?

Comment: Can you please what is your expected and actual out put to give more clarity

Comment: I am confused why it is ignoring multiple spaces

Answer (score 1):

**Answer as I understand the Question** 
Because you didn't provide much information.
I think you are not getting the correct count value as you expected.
The reason you're getting the wrong answer is that you checking the weather `b==true` and increase the counter. so, you will only get the count of first letters in the words of your string.

so to get the count, new main method

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String name = "This           is              my  first demo";
        int count = 0;
        boolean b=true;
        for(char c : name.toCharArray()){
            if (c==' '){
                b=true;
            }else{
                b=false;
                count+=1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
}
```

Here is what I have done was convert the string into a character array and loop through it and assign each value to the `char c` variable and check whether the value is ' '(space), if not I increase the count by one and there is no need to specify a `boolean b`. Because it won't do anything .

Without `boolean b` code get much more simpler,

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String name = "This           is              my  first demo";
        int count = 0;
        for(char c : name.toCharArray()){
            if (c!=' '){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
}
```

now I just check whether the value of `char c` not a ' '(space) and increase the count by one.

Comment: *no need to specify a boolean b there is no use for the code* - that's for sure

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't counting spaces, it's counting "words" by looking at non-space characters that either are at the start of the string or follow a space. Multiple spaces are ignored.

When I run the program, I get `5` as the output. I added logging before each time the count is incremented:

```
System.out.println("Incrementing at " + i);
count = count+1;
```

This results in this output:

```
Incrementing at 0
Incrementing at 15
Incrementing at 31
Incrementing at 35
Incrementing at 41
```